# Javascript file is not being loaded

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular1.6

HTML code to load all the files
Javascript files UserController.js and RepoController.js are not getting loaded and so not displayed in the developer tools source tab.When I press F5 in network tab files are loaded but operations are not being done.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular World</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Javascript/Route/Route.js"></script>
    <script src="../Javascript/Service/Service.js"></script>
    <script src="../Javascript/Controller/MainController.js"></script>
    <script src="../Javascript/Controller/UserController.js"></script>
    <script src="../Javascript/Controller/RepoController.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <h1>Github User/Repo Search</h1>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

Javascript controller function :

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('app');

    var UserController = function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, userRepoService) {
        $scope.userHeader = 'User Page';
        $scope.header1 = 'Index #';
        $scope.header2 = 'ID';
        $scope.header3 = 'Name';
        $scope.header4 = 'Size';
        $scope.header5 = 'Stargazers Count';
        $scope.header6 = 'Watchers';
        let username = $routeParams.username;

        let onReposComplete = function (data) {
            $scope.repos = data;
        };

        let onUserComplete = function (data) {
            $scope.user = data;
            userRepoService.getRepos($scope.user).then(onReposComplete);
        };

        let onError = function () {
            $scope.error = "Oops could not load user data";
        };

        userRepoService.getUser(username).then(onUserComplete , onerror);
    };

    app.controller('UserController', UserController);
}());
```

Service function:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('app');
    let userRepoService = function($http) {
        let getUser = function(username) {
            return $http.get('api.github.com/users/'; + username).then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            })
        };
        let getRepos = function(user) {
            return $http.get(user.repos_url).then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            })
        }
    };
    app.factory('userRepoService', userRepoService);
}());
```

Comment: Any console errors? Can you share `userRepoService` code?

Comment: @zooly In console it is showing usercontroller is not a function got undefined

Comment: try this `angular.module('app',[ ])` instead of `angular.module('app')`

Comment: Ramesh Rajendran  -  I have defined my module in routes file ,  so i cannot add another here , just using it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you have a javascript error in MainController.js which prevents to continue interprate next code.